# Show image on screen from ftp server

Tags: android, ftp, imageview

I almost build my android application, but i have some troubles. My app use a ftp connection to upload photos on a server and display on screen this photos. With "upload part" i have no problems, but when i choose a photo and i want to display it on screen, I encounter some problems. Seems like my image is blurred or fragmented. I think that is from redimensioning, but in this way i tried many algorithms ...unsuccessful
Please tell me how can I display on screen an image from this ftp server, image displayed at good quality without "blurred or fragmented" part, thank you

This is my "show image" class...

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class FaceDetection extends Activity {
public String o;
public ImageView viu;
public Bitmap bit;
public Bitmap myBitmap;
File file;
  InputStream a=null;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.poza);
  a=NextActivity.aa;
  viu=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  o=getIntent().getStringExtra("CaleOptiune");
            setData(o);
            initData();
          bit=getBit();
          viu.setImageBitmap(bit);

      }


 public Bitmap getBit(){          
       BitmapFactory.Options BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
       myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
         R.drawable.index, BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo);
       if(a!=null){Log.e("asdasdsadsadas","Streamul este incarcat");}else{Log.e("asdasdsadsadas","E nullllllll");}
       myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new BufferedInputStream(a));
       return myBitmap;
 }



 public void initData(){

       File file=new File(o);
       try {
        Log.e("Fisierul curent este",""+Logare.ftpClient.getWorkingDirectory());
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
       Log.e("File","Fisier creat din calea "+o);
       Log.e("File name",""+file.getName());
    try {
        a = Logare.ftpClient.ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(file.getName());
        Logare.ftpClient.ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        Log.e("asdasdsadsadas","Nu s-a instantiat InputSteamul");
    }

  }


 public void setData(String o) {
    this.o = o;

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Decoding and showing images seems to be OK. You could improve it by [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

I'm not sure, but I think your problem should be this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066

Try to create class:

```
public class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

    public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        super(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
        while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
            long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
            if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                int by_te = read();
                if (by_te < 0) {
                    break; // we reached EOF
                } else {
                    bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                }
            }
            totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
        }
        return totalBytesSkipped;
    }
}
```

and use:

`bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(entity.getContent()));`

Comment: i tried this class but... doesn't work... I encounter the same problem(s)

Comment: Ok, can you please send printScreen of badly loaded picture? Thanx.

Comment: I have some problems with decodeStream too, but not like this. Have you tried it on another device? And `decodeResource` is working without bugs? According the image it seems that some pixels are skipped. Try to decode another image (e.g. from wikipedia) and you will see where could be a problem.

Comment: i've been tried to run my app on different devices, but i encounter the same problem... and decodeResource seems to work fine... in logCat everything is ok ....   however thx for support :D

Comment: RESOLVED !!!... I just add tihs piece of code client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); ...

Comment: @alex Did you also use FlushedInputStream, or did you just add client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); in your activity?

Comment: just add "client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);" :D